# Laravel, api call slow first time (repeated call after 5s)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I work on a Vagrant+Puppet LAMP (2x cores, 2.5GB) stack where I develop my Laravel ver.8 based API.
There is a default setup, JWT middleware and almost bare minimum (also try with a bare fresh install with same behaviour). After the first call, the response time is about 6 seconds. If I call the same API endpoint, the response time is 200ms. Each further call within 3 seconds interval is quick. If I pause the calls for > 3s and then call again, the response time is again slow at about 6s.

Attempts I made to solve this:

```
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload -a --apcu
php artisan config:cache
php artisan session:table
php artisan migrate

.env:
APP_DEBUG=false
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1
MEMCACHED_PORT=11217
```

BTW, the api call returns only: return response()->json(['tst']); When I output phpinfo(); from index.php, the response time is each time (pausing to) about 70ms.

Also try to debug the calls with CacheGrind via Xdebug: XDEBUG_PROFILE=1. Here are the profiling results: https://filebin.net/izs3qm0gm3gt8jq6

I just mentioned that the autoloader takes longer but could not compare the results. Is there any way to figure out the issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Setup clockwork so you can analyze all the activity when you try to hit some end-point

just simply run

`composer require itsgoingd/clockwork`

you'll get an interface like this to check all the data

[image]

Another option is to use laravel telescope https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/telescope
But this requires database setup and record all logs on the database, and I personally like clockwork,

but both should tell you whats wrong with your setup

Comment: Actually I had all 3x installed + DevToolbar. There was not more output than the profiler output. Therefor I added them to my question, since there is a visible jump at certain processes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this approach. After installing it, this made more clear that the processing time is not fault of the slow responses. Just for the record, the reason for it is the long DNS Lookup for my local environment. Due an unknown reason, this is as described above. I will have to figure out a solution for it but also maybe setting direct IP->virtual Host would do it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was the long DNS Lookup on the Vagrant box - not Laravel or any other part of it.